# Remote server array args in for loop

Tags: bash

I need to pass values from an array to the script on remote host.

The remote script creates files locally on each array value.

Yes, i can do it by:

```
for i in ${LIST[@]}
do ssh root@${servers} bash "/home/test.sh" "$i"
done
```

but this action is rather slow and it makes ssh session on every array value

```
ssh root@${servers} bash "/home/test.sh" "${LIST[@]}"
```

by this code i get an error:

bash: line 1338:  command not found

How can i do it?

Comment: The loop should run on the remote server, but that could be tricky to set up correctly since the array is only on the local host. One option might be to use the `ControlMaster` option so that one `ssh` process authenticates and stays open. Most of the time between starting `ssh` and starting the remote command is spent authenticating, so that would speed up your local loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the connection-sharing feature of `ssh` so that you only have a single, preauthenticated connection that is used by each `ssh` process in your loop.

```
# This is the socket all of the following ssh processes will use
# to establish a connection to the remote host.
socket=~/.ssh/ssh_mux

# This starts a background process that does nothing except keep the
# authenticated connection open on the specified socket file.
ssh -N -M -o ControlPath="$socket" root@${servers} &

# Each ssh process should start much more quickly, as it doesn't have to
# go through the authentication protocol each time.
for i in "${LIST[@]}"; do
  # This uses the existing connection to avoid having to authenticate again
  ssh -o ControlPath="$socket" root@${servers} "bash /home/test.sh '$i'"

  # The above command is still a little fragile, as it assumes that $i
  # doesn't have a single quote in its name.
done

# This closes the connection master
ssh -o ControlPath="$socket" -O exit root@{servers}
```

---

The alternative is to try to move your loop into the remote command, but this is fragile as the array isn't defined on the remote host, and there is no good way to transfer each element in a way that protects each element. If you weren't concerned about word-splitting, you could use

```
ssh root@${servers} "for i in ${LIST[*]}; do bash /home/test.sh \$i; done"
```

but then you probably wouldn't be using an array in the first place.

Comment: before ssh socket ControlPath: time real    3m53.832s
after ssh socket ControlPath: real    0m16.073s

Thank you!